# What is the agent responsible for direction of current density $\vec{J}$?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, electrons, electric-current

This is the question:

> Consider a current carrying wire (current I) in the shape of a circle. Note that as the current progresses along the wire, the direction of $\vec{J}$ (current density) changes in an exact manner, while the current I remains unaffected. The agent that is essentially responsible for is
>
> A) Source of Emf
>
> B) electric field produced by charges accumulated on the surface of wire.
>
> C) the charges just behind a given segment of wire which push them just the right way by repulsion
>
> D) The charges ahead

And the answer is given to be B , but I don't agree with this , I always thought that the direction of current density is given by the direction of drift velocity of electrons , I don't know how option B got to be the answer
It is just given that as $\vec{J} = \sigma \vec{E}$ It is given to be the agent responsible for the direction of current density but the E is the electric field of source and the electron's field might not be in the same direction of the field of source, even if its the direction of electron charges accumulate so a likely accumulation can make the wire burst?

What is your take on this question and what might be your answer, please feel free to correct me anywhere I am wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer B is indeed correct. Since this is a conductor we know that there is a relationship between the current density and the E field: $$\vec J=\sigma \vec E$$ Since $\vec J$ turns as it goes around the loop, that means $\vec E$ must also turn as it goes around the loop.

So the question is, what can cause the E field to change direction?

The answer is surface charges. The surface charges on the wire produce the E field which follows around the loop. The surface charges produce a discontinuity in the E field between the inside and the outside of the wire.

This is my favorite paper on the topic:

Rainer Mueller, “A semiquantitative treatment of surface charges in DC circuits”, Am. J. Phys. 80 (9), September 2012

https://www.tu-braunschweig.de/index.php?eID=dumpFile&t=f&f=138440&token=2cc8a71e4fdbf159121c6b8ef8348952a2e0c197

Comment: My reasoning is wrong then , thank you for the explanation sir! And thank you very much for the link to a paper It provides a chance for me to deeply understand what is exactly happening

Comment: Just a quick question this surface charge is external or the electrons themselves deposit as surface charge ?

Comment: The surface charges come from the charge carriers in the conductor.

Comment: Ok thank you very much !